# What's the meaning of "try me"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I read a comic and a character uses this word when the day is over and the other character said he experienced something unusual. So what's the meaning of *try me*? What is the something to try? Why *me*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "try me" is used to suggest that someone may be willing to do something **unexpected** or **unlikely** (OED):

> You won't use the gun here. - Try me *(meaning: Oh, yes I will. If you don't believe me and think that it's unlikely, I'll show you that I can use the gun here).*
>
> You probably don't know the answer. - Try me *(meaning: I might know the answer; give me a chance to answer the question).*
>
> I guess you don't know who this man is. - Try me *(meaning: Let me prove you that you're wrong).*

Comment: So it's not something like _Try (something omitted) (to) me_? I'm also thinking about how this phrase is formed.

Comment: @user7813604 consider it an idiom - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Try+me

Comment: @user7813604 grammatically speaking, it's the imperative mood

Comment: @user7813604 no, it's not like "Try (something omitted) (to) me"

Comment: So it's something like _Try = Ask_ in this idiom?

Comment: @user7813604 yes, something like that

Comment: In a number of situations, someone may say "Try me" in a way that means "You may ask me". That tend to be used in situations where someone thinks the other person may be reluctant to ask them for some reason. From what you said had just happened in the comic, it sounds like the person is asking, "Do you want to talk about it?" By saying "Try me" they are indicating the other person doesn't need to be scared of causing offence by talking about something 'unusual'.

Comment: @RossMurray: Your comment is actually pretty good for me, thanks :)